# How can I train artificial intelligence for background removing on video?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

How can I train artificial intelligence for background removing and human body extracting on video?

Which AI algorithm is the best for human extraction?

Comment: This question is better on DataScience stack exchange. If you want it moved there, you can flag it for moderator attention and request a move.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself? What are the insights you gained? Did you try searching for publications, e.g., via Google Scholar?

Comment: Thank you.I search google and find background removal techniques for background removal on images.But how can i do background removal techniques on videos?I think that i can do human body extraction frame by frame with background removal ai algorithms and 
put together this frames and create a background removal video but this method doesn't seem efficent.

Comment: That's already a good start. You should mention such things within the question to show that you have put some effort into this. Do you have a data set already?

Comment: Yes, I have a dataset that contain sample videos and background removal videos created by sample videos.Accordingly I use supervised learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot say which algorithm truly is the best one for this task.
Since it is basically task with image/video data, you will probably try deep learning with CNNs first.

You can either work on each frame individually, or you can process the whole video. There is also a range of options in between.

### Single frame

Working on one frame at a time makes your problem simple.
It reduces to an image segmentation/background separation task.

You can start with a pretrained CNN architecture from the literature, like VGGNet, Inception, Resnet. Remove the last layers and fit it to your problem.

The downside is that you lose a lot of information by restricting yourself to single frames.

### Small windows

You can take more information into account by feeding some past (or even future) frames into your architecture. Alternatively you can also compute some gradients (like optical flow) as features and add them to your image.

With this approach, you can still use a CNN architecture.

## Long sequences RNN

If you want to process longer sequences, and possible in an hopefully efficient way, you should look into recurrent neural networks.
You would have recurrence over time, and convolution over the spatial dimensions. In my opinion, this is the best architecture for this task.

It also allows for online processing of live videos.

Comment: Thank you but I didn't understand how can i have a recurrence?

Comment: @generator I cannot explain this to you here. You have to read this up yourself. Google `recurrent neural network`.